# Split a value in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a value in one column like this: `PD 10256-P1`.

I want to split this information & only need the number `10256`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: is this format will remain fixed??

Comment: A more general question might be better - at the moment you imply that all the strings to be split start PD<space> and end -P1

Comment: Yes.. It will stars with PD & end with P along with number

Comment: you want it once or in every iteration of query

Comment: if you need data at front end then get whole column data and apply regex over the front end and if you need to work with column at backend it self then you have to create you own custom function which will give you the desired number you want after performing regex replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it by

```
SUBSTRING('PD 10256-P1', 4, 5)
```

it cuts your input to 5 character string starting from 4th character.

result is

```
10256
```

[Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here is generalised Format for you

`SELECT SUBSTRING('PD 10256-P1', CHARINDEX(' ', 'PD 10256-P1'), CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING('PD 10256-P1', CHARINDEX(' ', 'PD 10256-P1'), LEN('PD 10256-P1')))-1) AS RequiredString;`

You can replace 'PD 10256-P1' by your column name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it :

```
declare @var varchar(50)= 'PD 10256-P1'
select substring(@var,charindex(' ',@var,1), charindex('-p',@var,1)-charindex(' ',@var,1))
```